# Calculate shore distributions and correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, correlation

Task

We have depth of random vector:
$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\frac{1}{5} & \text{for } 0<x<1\;,2<y<7\\0 & \text{for other } x,y\end{cases}$$

**a) Calculate shore distributions**

**b) Correlation coefficient for X,Y**

================================================================

**a)**

$$f_X(x) =\begin{cases} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{5} \, dy= \frac{1}{5} & \text{for } 0<x<1 \\0 & \text{for other} \end{cases}$$

$f_Y(y)$ will also be $\frac{1}{5}$

**b)** Correlation coefficient is:
$$p(X,Y)= \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{ \sqrt{D^2 X}\sqrt{D^2 Y} } $$
$EX=(EX,EY) = (\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$

**what I don't know how to calculate in this task:**

$EXY=\text{?} \; (\frac{1}{25}?)$

$D^2 X=\text{?}$

$D^2 Y=\text{?}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I changed $fx(x)$ and $fy(y)$ to $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ with capital $X$ and capital $Y$ in the subscripts and lower-case $x$ and lower-case $y$ as the arguments. I wonder why some people sometimes write $f_x(x)$ instead of $f_X(x),$ i.e. how does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations in (a) are incorrect. Correct is
$$f_X(x) =\begin{cases} \int_2^7 \frac{1}{5}\mathop{dy}= 1 & \text{if } 0<x<1 \\0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$
For $Y$ we find that 
$$f_Y(y) =\begin{cases} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{5}\mathop{dx}= \frac{1}{5} & \text{if } 2<y<7 \\0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$

Your expected values are incorrect as well. For example, 
$$\mathbb E X = \int_0^1 x f_X(x) \mathop{dx} = \int_0^1 x  \mathop{dx}  = \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{1}{2}.$$ 
The variance is 
$$\operatorname{Var}X = \mathbb E (X^2) - (\mathbb EX)^2 = \int_0^1 x^2 f_X(x)\mathop{dx} - \frac{1}{4} = \int_0^1 x^2 \mathop{dx} - \frac{1}{4}= \frac{x^3}{3}\Bigr|_{x=0}^1 -\frac{1}{4}= \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}.$$ 
I leave the analogous calculations for $Y$ up to you.

Moreover, 
$$\mathbb E (XY) = \int_0^1\int_2^7 xyf(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}=\int_0^1\int_2^7 \frac{xy}{5} \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx} = \int_0^1\frac{xy^2}{10}\Bigr|_{y=2}^7 \mathop{dx} =\int_0^1\frac{9x}{2} \mathop{dx} = \frac{9}{4}.$$

If you succeeded in finding $\mathbb E Y$, you can calculate the covariance using $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E(XY) - \mathbb E X\mathbb E  Y$.

Comment: I tried monkeying Y the same way you did X. Equations I got are not elegant at all so I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Could you take a look? https://imgur.com/a/iVeHjcm Should It be $(1/5)y$  instead of y on intergrals?  (Sorry that its not latex, Ive been studying all day and are heading to bed now so my eyes won't handle typing commands)

Comment: You used the wrong density. The one for $Y$ does not equal 1, but 1/5. See above answer. So, you need to calculate e.g. $\mathbb E Y = \int_2^7 y f_Y(y) \mathop{dy} = \int_2^7 \frac y5  \mathop{dy}$. Btw, variances are never negative.